# MongoDB Aggregates in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to get a MongoDB aggregate to work in Java. The Mongo documentation (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/aggregation/) gives the following example:

```
collection.aggregate(
      Arrays.asList(
              Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("categories", "Bakery")),
              Aggregates.group("$stars", Accumulators.sum("count", 1))
      )
).forEach(printBlock);
```

So I guess they're grouping on the stars field, i.e., summing up the bakeries with different values for 'stars'; how many have one star, how many have two, etc. I do not understand what "count" is in this context, I guess the name of the resulting field, as in the 'count' of bakeries with that many stars? But I don't even have a guess about the '1' that is the second parameter to the `sum()` method.

I also want to filter, but instead of a sum I want the average of the values. The documentation for `avg` looks like it is similar to `sum`, and so I guess I will need a similar looking statement.

```
Aggregates.group("reading", Accumulators.avg("average", ?));
```

So do I have this right so far? And what goes where my question mark is? The mongo documentation for avg talks about an "expression that is applied to each value", but I don't know what that means in this context. I don't want anything applied to each value, I want each value to be added into a total that is then divided by the numbers of values at the end.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not understand what "count" is in this context, I guess the name of the resulting field, as in the 'count' of bakeries with that many stars?

Correct. In the example `count` is the name of the resulting field for [$sum operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/). Essentially this is similar to:

```
{"$group": {
    "_id": "$stars", 
    "count" : {"$sum": 1 }
}}
```

It's equivalent to saying, create a list of distinct values in field `stars` and count the number of occurrences of each values. An example result:

```
{ "_id" : 3, "count" : 100 }
{ "_id" : 2, "count" : 75 }
{ "_id" : 1, "count" : 50 }
```

> I don't even have a guess about the '1' that is the second parameter to the sum() method.

It's stating to increment by `1` for each value; or numeric value from the result of specified expression(s)

> And what goes where my question mark is? The mongo documentation for avg talks about an "expression that is applied to each value"

The value that goes into your question mark is an [expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions). For example, if you specify a [field path expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#field-path-and-system-variables) that would resolve into value of a field, the `$avg` will sum up the total field value of all documents in the collection and divide it up by the number of fields. For example:

```
Aggregates.group("reading", Accumulators.avg("average", "$field_with_numeric_value"));
```

See also [$avg operator behaviour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#behavior).